# jstack unable to print java thread stacks from Windows crash dump

Tags: java, crash-dumps, jmap, jstack

I'm trying to extract a java heap dump from a native dump taken by WER when it crashed:

```
jstack -m -l "c:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe" WER.tmp.hdmp
```

but I get the following exception:

```
Attaching to core c:\Users\xxx\Desktop\WER.tmp.hdmp from executable c:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe, please wait...
sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.NoSuchSymbolException: Could not find symbol "gHotSpotVMTypes" in any of the known library names (jvm.dll, jvm_g.dll)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotTypeDataBase.lookupInProcess(HotSpotTypeDataBase.java:389)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotTypeDataBase.readVMTypes(HotSpotTypeDataBase.java:104)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotTypeDataBase.<init>(HotSpotTypeDataBase.java:85)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.bugspot.BugSpotAgent.setupVM(BugSpotAgent.java:565)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.bugspot.BugSpotAgent.go(BugSpotAgent.java:494)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.bugspot.BugSpotAgent.attach(BugSpotAgent.java:348)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:169)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.main(JStack.java:86)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.runJStackTool(JStack.java:118)
        at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.main(JStack.java:84)
Debugger attached successfully.
jstack requires a java VM process/core!
```

I've double checked that:

- I'm running the same version of java as the system that the crash occurred on
- The bitness of Windows (32) matches the system that the crash occurred on
- jvm.dll is in the path
- windbg is installed

I get exactly the same error if I try to extract a java heap dump using jmap.

Does anyone know what could be going wrong?

Comment: I encountered this sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.NoSuchSymbolException exception once when using jinfo. It turned out that I was trying to use "jinfo" provided by hotpot vm on a process created by jrockit vm.